# How to know if a word in a string has digits?

Tags: c++

The question I have: How can you tell if a word in a string has a digit in it or not?

What I need to do: write a program that reads in a line of text and outputs the line with all the digits in all integer numbers replaced with 'x'.

For example:

> My userID is john17 and my 4 digit pin is 1234 which is secret.

It should become

> My userID is john17 and my x digit pin is xxxx which is secret.

Notice how the digits in john17 does not get affected.

The code I have so far:

```
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
    string str;
    int i;

    cout << "Enter a line of text: ";
    getline(cin, str);

    for (i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
        {
            str.at(i) = 'x';
        }
    }

    cout << "Edited text: " << str << endl;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to something like `str.find_first_of("0123456789")`?

Comment: You may find `isdigit` helpful too

Comment: @mathematician1975 okay I think I have something figured out. I will try it out and get back to you.

Comment: Have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex.  For numbers in the middle of your string, you need a regex match with " \d+ ".  You also need to match with strings at the beginning and end of your text, and those that precede punctuation marks.

Comment: You can always use regular expressions: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Comment: What about `17q`?  What about `17.`?  `17.65` is a floating point number, but `PIN is 17.` is an integer plus punctuation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of methods that you can use. Below are some of them:

1 - A generic algorithm:

1. Iterate through the string:
   For example: `"My userID is john17 and my 4 digit pin is 1234 which is secret."`
2. Set a boolean flag (`IsNumberOnly=true`)when you find a digit immediately after a `space` character and start caching the word. Please note that the flag is `false` originally. For example the second `'1'` in your example is a digit immediately after a `space` character. Continue iterating,
3. If you find a nondigit before reaching another `space` set `IsNumberOnly=false`,
4. Finish the word. If `IsNumberOnly=true` then print `'x'`s (the number of characters in the word cashed) else print the cashed word, e.g., `17John`.

Please note that here `john17` will not be affected at all. Even it was `17john` it would not have been affected.

OR

2 - If you want to use The Library and C++11 then you can read and test the words one by one with:

```
std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), ::isdigit); // C++11
```

For more details and examples:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of

OR

3 - Something like this will do the trick:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    cout << "Enter a line of text: ";
    getline(cin,str);

    istringstream iss(str);
    string word;
    string finalStr="";
    while(iss >> word) {
        if(word.find_first_not_of( "0123456789" ) == string::npos)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<word.size(); i++)
            {
                finalStr+='x';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            finalStr.append(word);
        }
        finalStr+=' ';
    }

    cout << "Edited text: " << finalStr << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Those are all just some examples.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

for any digit you found, check if it starting new word.

if it does, replace till the sequence of digits end.

it will work if name can't start with a digit.

for example:

```
for( size_t i=str.find_first_of("0123456789"); i!=string::npos; i=str.find_first_of("0123456789",i+1)){ 
   if (i == 0 || str.at(i-1) == ' '){
      do{
          str.at(i) = 'x';
          i++;
      }while( isdigit( str.at(i)));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use `std::all_of` along with `std::isdigit`, something like this:

```
std::string input("My userID is john17 and my 4 digit pin is 1234 which is secret.");

std::istringstream buffer(input);
std::transform(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(buffer),
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "),
    [](std::string const &s) -> std::string {
        if (std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), isdigit))
            return std::string(s.length(), 'x');
        return s;
    });
```

Note that as it stands right now this has undefined behavior: if your input includes any characters that are negative numbers when encoded into `char` (e.g., characters with accents, umlauts, etc. in ISO 8859-*) then the behavior of `isdigit` is undefined. Each character must be cast to `unsigned char` before being passed to `isdigit` to give defined behavior in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

As always, STL provide many tools to do it relatively easily.

Here I show how to use stream iterator, all_of algorithm combined with isdigit predicate. The idea is to tokenise the input into words and if all character of the token are digits then replace it with x's.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <locale>

int main(int, char**)
{
    using iterator = std::istream_iterator<std::string>;
    auto const& end = iterator();

    for (auto it = iterator(std::cin); it != end; ++it) {
        auto const& token = *it;
        if (std::all_of(std::begin(token), std::end(token), [](auto&& c) { return std::isdigit(c, std::locale()); })) {
            std::cout << std::string(token.size(), 'x') << " ";
        } else {
            std::cout << token << " ";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And you can see it [live here](http://ideone.com/N0PSpJ).

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative using the `find_first_of` and `find_first_not_of`. Will work no matter where the digits are in the word:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
   std::string str = "M3y u1serID is 7j2ohn17 and my 4 digit pin is 1234 which is secret.";
   std::istringstream iss(str);
   std::string word;
   while(iss >> word) 
   {
       if (word.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == std::string::npos) {
           std::cout << std::string(word.size(), 'x') << " ";
       } else {
           std::cout << word << " ";
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your input format is always Look like this?

My userID is john17 and my 4 digit pin is 1234 which is secret.

Then just check whether there is a space before the digits or not. If yes then change the number with xxxxx else not.

Comment: Please improve your written English skills.  I am a fluent English speaker and I cannot make any sense of your first sentence.